# Read multiple images and labels in python

Tags: python, opencv, dataset

I have dataset that consist of 100 folders and each of folders contain some images as shown below. How do I read this images and labels so that if I call the folder label, it will have collection of the images? (for example if I call Cat label, it will consist of img_001 and img_032 not just img_001 or img_032). I have tried using dictionary as my code below, but the dictionary only takes the first image of each folder, whereas I want to takes all images. How to do this? Thank you

```
(Folder Structure)
Cat:
 -img_001.jpg
 -img_032.jpg
Dog:
 -img_002.jpg
 -img_012.jpg
 -img_011.jpg
 -img_000.jpg
Bird:
 -img_003.jpg
... until 100 folders
```

```
(My code)
path = 'animal/'
img_dict = dict()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print(os.path.basename(root))
    my_key = os.path.basename(root)

    for file_ in files:
        full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file_)
        img = cv2.imread(full_file_path)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img_dict[my_key] = img
```

```
(Output using my code with only one images per labels)
Cat:
 -img_001.jpg
Dog:
 -img_002.jpg
Bird:
 -img_003.jpg
... until end of dictionary (100 labels)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a folder name as a key for the dictionary.
To store several files in this case you should use a list type as a value.
Using [] as a literal for list creation and the append() method to append a value to the list, try to do like this:

```
path = 'animal/'
img_dict = dict()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print(os.path.basename(root))
    my_key = os.path.basename(root)

    dir_images = []
    for file_ in files:
        full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file_)
        img = cv2.imread(full_file_path)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        dir_images.append(img)

    img_dict[my_key] = dir_images
```