# How to read images and Labels in batches

Tags: python

[Read multiple images and labels in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813201/read-multiple-images-and-labels-in-python)

This is what I want to do. However, I want to read it in batches.
Is it possible to do this?

I am not planning to use default function of Keras and Tensorflow.

```
path = 'path to dir'
img_dict = dict()
a=[]
batch_tuple=()

def batching(batch=5):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        my_key = os.path.basename(root)
        dir_images = []
        dir_labels=[]
        for file_ in files:
            dir_images.append(full_file_path)

        for ndx in range(0, len(dir_images), batch):
            batch_img #list2
            batch_lab #list1
            return (batch_img,batch_lab)

         
while batch:
    if 100<batch:
        t=next()
        print(t)     
    batch-=batch
        
# print(len(a))
```

I get expected result when I do following code -:

But I actually want to do using the function. like if I pass the batch size, it will return my expected output!

in every iteration, I want to get a tuple of two lists that I can print in the second code.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i added it, let me know if I need to add more details @petezurich

Answer (score 1):

in this line `print((batch_img,batch_lab))`

create a list and do as following-:

```
empy_list=[]
empy_list.append((batch_img,batch_lab))
```

no need to go with while loop i think!

i think this will give what you are expecting!